# Selective character count (only non-alphanumeric)?

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge (Easy)

> Write a function which takes an argument and returns the number of non-alphanumeric characters found.

### Challenge (Hard)

> Write a function which takes an argument and returns the number of bytes used to store the number of non-alphanumeric characters found.  (ie: include calculation for multi-byte characters.)

### Rules / Notes

- Alphanumeric in this case is defined as:

  `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
  `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
  `0123456789`
- A null character should count as 0 characters, but as 1 byte when stored.

  `NUL`
- Showing multi-byte support (if too complicated) only has to demonstrate one character set or language reference / codepage (if this actually matters.  I don't know, so just putting it out there.)

### Winner

Since this is code golf, the shortest code that correctly matches the challege wins.

Comment: Require to support multibyte char? Require UTF8?

Comment: For C non-unicode they are just same challenge?

Comment: @l4m2 "Showing multi-byte support (if too complicated) only has to demonstrate one character set or language reference / codepage"

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 14 characters

```
y/A-Za-z0-9//c
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>7</strike> <strike>6</strike> 4 bytes

```
ḟØBL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmHZzj5/P//3wMokK8Qnl@Uk2IQb2ykCAA)

```
ḟØBL
ḟ         reverse ḟilter: remove all of the input characters that are also in...
 ØB       alphanumeric characters...
   L      and get the Length of the resulting string!
```

**6-byte solution:**

```
ḟØWṖ¤L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmHZ4Q/3Dnt0BKf////ewBF81XC84tyUpTjAQ)

```
ḟØWṖ¤L
ḟ         reverse ḟilter: remove all of the input characters that are also in...
 ØWṖ¤     the "word" character class with the underscore popped from it, taken as a nilad...
     L    ...and take the length of the resulting string
```

Comment: You can use `(nilad) (links) ¤` as a new nilad, like so: `ḟØWṖ¤L`

Comment: Alternatively, `ØWṖ⁸ḟL` works too, of course. (That `⁸ḟ` is the [fourth monad chain pattern](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Tutorial#how-do-we-walk-down-the-chain).)

Comment: @Lynn Thank you! I wasn't able to understand `¤` from the docs before but now I understand it!

Comment: You can use `ØB` (push `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`) instead of `ØWṖ¤` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, thanks! Don't know why I didn't catch that nilad when I was making this.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax) (Easy)

```
├Dr
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=c34472&i=This_i%24_A_T3st%21)

**Explanation**

```
VL-%        # Full program, unpacked
VL          # Push "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  -         # Remove all elements in b from a.
    %       # Length and implicitly print result
```

Comment: Dang, ninja'd me by a minute! My solution was identical. I'd describe `VL` as `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` rather than as many separate elements.

Comment: @Scrooble Yeah that is what I had it as originally, but I thought it looked too long, so I formatted it like that to be more concise. I see how they could be viewed at differently. I'll change it to be like you recommended though.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy

### Easy: <strike>26</strike> <strike>25</strike> 30 characters

```
c={(it=~/[[^\00\w]_]/).size()}

assert c("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789")== 2
assert c("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")==0
assert c("a-b-7*NNuah ~#77%")==7
assert c('_|') == 2
assert c('\0') == 0
```

### Hard: 47 characters

```
s={it.replaceAll(/[\w&&[^_]]/,'').bytes.size()}

assert s("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789")== 2
assert s("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")==0
assert s("a-b-7*NNuah ~#77%")==7
assert s('_') == 1
```

Comment: Is that `|` supposed to be in the first regex?

Comment: I thought it was... but looks unnecessary :) thanks

Comment: Looked to me like a bug, because I think it would have messed up the counts in strings with a `|`.

Comment: Waiting for some other entries, but nice go at it.  Have you tried running some Chinese or Japanese characters into the hard function to see if it counts them properly?

Comment: I don't see you handling `'\0'` in easy (they should also be excluded)

Comment: @ratchet Good point re: `NUL`; @cbroughton will check with some japanese...

Comment: @cbroughton hard answer will use default charset of whatever system it's run on, and should accurately count storage size, although may struggle if e.g. Japanese characters are not supported in that character set

Answer (score 1):

## D

### easy (29 chars)

```
count!"!isAlphaNum(b)&&b"(s);
```

### hard (35 chars)

`s` needs to be a `char[]`

```
s.length-count!"!isAlphaNum(b)"(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 42 bytes

-26 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
function(x)nchar(gsub('[[:alnum:]]',"",x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBC4IwGEDv/Qr9DLaBhlJYWB465alTESES6pxKcwu3hf36pe/4eG@0zDkFjmVG1LqXAk9E1F054laZCqM8T0ouzJAUBfIB/IkQyzBQw360jw/7bcR2X0Zb/eYL8czteb9kQLw0DVdzmjWcy/VDjpx6LyCzQmrDG9HqLqilEdoFt1dn/unKqxlwRQArckTLH4X2Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (easy)

```
žKмg
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6D7vC3vS//9/tmdRiXFxydO10@sUAQ)

**Explanation:**

```
žK      # Push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  м     # Remove all occurrences of this second string from the input string
   g    # Push and implicitly output the length of the result
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (hard)

```
žKмÇεDžy‹i1ë.²<5÷>н]O
```

Thanks to *@Mr.Xcoder* for helping me put two sub-solutions together with `D`, and explaining how `]` closes both the if-statement and foreach-loop. (I accidentally placed the `D` before the `ε` and used one `}` instead of two..)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf8wNWFiMWX//8W@S9C8w4fOtUTFvnnigLlpMcOrLsKyPDXDtz7QvV1P///mvKJ0ZXN05a2XfiE)

**Explanation:**

```
žK                     # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  м                    # Remove all occurrences of this second string from the input string
   Ç                   # Convert each character to its unicode value
    εD                 # Foreach over this list
         i             #  If the current item
        ‹              #  is maller than
      žy               #  128
          1            #   Use 1
           ë           #  Else
            .²         #   Use log_2
              <        #   minus 1
               5÷      #   integer-divided by 5
                 >     #   plus 1
                  н    #  Take the head of the sublists
                   ]   # Close both the if-else and for-each (shorter version of `}}`)
                    O  # Sum everything together
```

05AB1E doesn't have any builtins for knowing the amount of bytes a character costs, so I'm converting them to unicode values with `Ç` and use the following pseudo-code to determine their bytes:

```
if(unicodeValue < 128)
  return 1
else
  return log_2(unicodeValue-1)//5+1    # (where // is integer-division)
```

Pseudo-code inspired by [*@TheBikingViking*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83798/52210) for the [*Bytes/Characters* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83673/bytes-character).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes (easy)

```
#(¬□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X1nj0JpH0xb@///fIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFEQA)

#### Explanation

Pretty simple usage of `isanum` (`□`):

```
#(¬□)  -- example: "Input!"
#(  )  -- count number of
 ( □)  -- | is alphanumeric: [73,110,112,117,116,0]
 (¬ )  -- | not: [0,0,0,0,0,1]
       -- : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## MS-SQL, 85 bytes (easy)

```sql
SELECT SUM(1)FROM spt_values,t
WHERE type='P'AND SUBSTRING(v,number,1)LIKE'[^a-z0-9]'
```

Handles strings up to 2047 characters. [Per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), input is taken via a pre-existing table **t** with `varchar` field **v**.

This must be run in the `master` database (which exists on every SQL server). This database has a system table `dbo.spt_values`, which, if we filter by `type='P'`, contains counting numbers from 0 to 2047. Join that to our input table to split each character into its own row, then count up those that match the `LIKE` filter (which supports character ranges).

## MS-SQL, 85 bytes (hard)

```sql
SELECT SUM(2)FROM spt_values,t
WHERE type='P'AND SUBSTRING(v,number,1)LIKE'[^a-z0-9]'
```

You also need to change the input table to an `nvarchar` field **v** instead of `varchar`.

So yeah, this is kind of cheaty, because the [nvarchar data type uses 2 bytes for *every* character](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), even for normal ASCII characters. That means I don't have to distinguish between characters that *could* be stuffed into a single byte and those that can't. But it does strictly satisfy the challenge, since it reflects the number of bytes that SQL is actually using to store `nvarchar` strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 1.8

### easy (48 chars)

`function f(s)(s.match(/[^a-z0-9]/gi)||[]).length`

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, easy, 44

```
filter e{($args-replace"[a-z0-9]").Length}
```

If we stretch the definition of »arguments«, we can shorten it a bit more (**41**):

```
filter e{($_-replace"[`0a-z0-9]").Length}
```

but it then requires input to be sent via the pipeline.

### PowerShell, hard, 71

```
function x{[text.encoding]::utf8.GetByteCount($args-replace'[a-z0-9]')}
```

Again, if we allow the pipeline we get it to **68**:

```
function x{[text.encoding]::utf8.GetByteCount($_-replace'[a-z0-9]')}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala

### Easy (43 chars)

```
def c(s:String)=s.count(!_.isLetterOrDigit)
```

### Hard (58 chars)

```
def c(s:String)=s.filter(!_.isLetterOrDigit).getBytes.size
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python

### easy (39 chars)

```
f=lambda s:sum(1-i.isalpha()for i in s)
```

Comment: You can remove the `f=` to save 2 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck

### Easy (1397 chars)

```
>+[,[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>-[<->+++++]<--->>>+<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[
<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>+>+<<
<-]>>[<<+>>-]>>-[<<->>---------]>>+<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[
-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]>----[<+>----]<++>>>+
<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->
]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[[-]<<[>>+<+<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<+>>>[-]]][-
]<[-]<[-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<<->>>[-]]<<[>>+<+<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<[-]->>>[-]][-]<[-]<[-]
<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>>--[<<->>---]<<++++>>>>+<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>
[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]>--[<->
+++++]<----->>>+<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]
>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[[-]<<[>>+<+<-]>[<+>
-]>[<<<+>>>[-]]][-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<<->>>[-]]<<[>>+<+<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<[-]-
>>>[-]][-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>>----[<<+++>>--]>>+<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<
[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>>>[-]<[-]<[-]
<[-]<[-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<<->>>[-]]<<[>>+<+<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<[-]->>>[-]][-]<[-]<[-]<[
<<+>>[-]]<----------]>--[<->+++++]<--<-[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>>>>-[<->+++
++]<---[<+>-]<.[-]++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>>>>-[<->+++++]<---[<+
<+>>-]<.<.
```

All hand coded. It takes input until it gets a 0xA character signifying end of input (not counted). Only handles up to 255 nonalphanumeric input characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl (easy) 27 characters**

```
sub _{$_=shift;(s/\W|_//g)}
```

**usage:**

```
say _('@abc_123ABC -("~ abc')   
---> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby, easy, 32**

```
f=->s{s.scan(/[^a-z0-9]/i).size}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), Easy, 26 bytes

```
iEh$"0:A[a{"{16F@2k)S^|}~+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9M1Q0XJwMoxOrFaqdrQzM3BKFszOK6mtk77/38FRSVlFVU1dQ1NLW0dXT19A0MjYxNTM3MLSytrG1s7ewdHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP/@AwKDgkNCw8IjIqOiY2Lj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisqqaqANAA)

#### How it works

```
iEh$"0:A[a{"{16F@2k)S^|}~+

iEh                         Take input as char; if EOF, print the top as int and halt
   $                        Move the input under the char counter
    "0:A[a{"                Push six boundary chars
            {1              Pull the input to the top, and push 1 (XOR counter)
                            (Stack: [char counter, ...boundary, input, XOR counter])
              6F      |     Repeat 6 times...
                @             Pull a boundary char to the top
                 2k)          Copy the input char and compare (boundary > input)
                    S^        XOR with the XOR counter
                            (Stack: [char counter, input, XOR counter])
                       }~+  Move XOR counter to bottom, discard input, and
                              add to the char counter
                            Repeat indefinitely
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth)

### Easy, 17 bytes

```
l:z"[a-zA-Z0-9]"k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8eqSik6UbfKUTfKQNcyVin7/38FRSVlFVU1dQ1NLW0dXT19A0MjYxNTM3MLSytrG1s7ewdHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP/@AwKDgkNCw8IjIqOiY2Lj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisqq6praOgA)

### Hard, 30 bytes

```
/lsm.[\08.BCd:z"[a-zA-Z0-9]"k8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xz@nOFcvOsbAQs/JOcWqSik6UbfKUTfKQNcyVinb4v//h/v3AgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 42 bytes (easy)

```java
s->s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]","").length()
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dY5NigIxEIX3fYoyuEjABGFWgyj0AXSjK0WaGKNGY2y6SkGlvcbs3XsDrzNeo41/SzcF9ep99d5S77RcTleV8RoRutqFYwLgAtlipo2F3mN9CmB4nwoX5oCiFcUyiQNJkzPQgwBtqFB2UBU295FMvedslMqhloem/B2zBmNCeRvmtOCiaj3ofDvxkX4/2W3cFNaxwTtnNAYtXvH9PZJdq82WVB5P5AMPynB2u57JIv1f/k6nGhPPXt/dg4XDzNWzNBv8IH38ZVJWdw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                               // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]","")  //  Remove all digits and letters
   .length()                      //  And return the length
```

---

## Java 10, 102 bytes (hard)

```java
s->{int r=0;for(var c:s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]","").split(""))r+=c.getBytes("utf8").length;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fY@/TsMwEMb3PMVhMTiCWJVYACtIQWKkSztRVZFxncTFdSL7EihV@hrs7LwBrwOvERwoCwPL6f58d9/v1qITyXr1MEgjvIdboe0uAtAWlSuEVDAdy@8GSDpDp20JPgasXP3o4eZJqgZ1bXlQ9VEIHgVqCVOwkMLgk6vduOrSCS9qRzvhQF565lRjwvXMGEoWWXInkudJcrEkp4TEzDdGIw1Z7E5SyUqF11tUnpIWi/MwN8qWWHGnsHUWHO8HPjo37b0JzgeArtYr2IR3DtCLJYj4L/XPb7OtR7VhdYusCVI0llomKfl8fw22@PH2st8fBRr@r3peaZ/r4zzL52cef/V91A9f)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                              // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0;                        //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  for(var c:s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]","")
                                  //  Remove all digits and letters
             .split(""))          //  And loop over the remaining characters
    r+=                           //   Add to the result-sum:
      c.getBytes("utf8").length;  //    The UTF-8 bytes of the current character
  return r;}                      //  Return the result-sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>58</s> 52 bytes (easy)

<sub>-6 bytes, thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni?tab=profile) (inverting the test, using `elem` instead)!</sub>

```hs
f s=sum[1|c<-s,elem c":;<=>?@[\\]^_`"||c>'z'||c<'0']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2La4NDfasCbZRrdYJzUnNVchWcnK2sbWzt4hOiYmNi4@QammJtlOvUodSNmoG6jH/s9NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1HQU0hTsLWxUUhPLXHOzytJzSsp/u8BNDtfRyE8vygnRREA)

Comment: 51 bytes: [```f s=sum[1|c<-s,elem c":;<=>?[\\]^_`"||c>'z'||c<'0']```](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2La4NDfasCbZRrdYJzUnNVchWcnK2sbWzj46JiY2Lj5BqaYm2U69Sh1I2agbqMf@z03MzFOwVSgoyswrUdBTSFOwtbFRSE8tcc7PK0nNKyn@7wE0Ol9HITy/KCdFEQA).

Comment: @Laikoni: Thanks! (you missed one though: `@`)